# Infrequently getting errors for Sandbox service

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

Occasionally affecting some long time process and making users frustrated.
Googled and found nothing, one would expect `6616` or `EventCode=20257` points to something but I could not find anything.

My guess is that under heavy load fails? I wonder if I move all plugins out of the sandbox would solve the issue.

Below is the event log:

> LogName=Application SourceName=MSCRMSandboxService EventCode=20257
>       EventType=2 Type=Error ComputerName= TaskCategory=%1 OpCode=None
>       RecordNumber=2033209 Keywords=Classic Message=The Sandbox Host
>       service has encountered an unexpected error and has stopped. Source:
>       Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService.exe (6616) Error:
>       System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>       'SandboxWorker.{d60c83a8-807f-4121-8d16-86351fc98c02}.txt' because
>       it is being used by another process.    at
>       System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) 
>       at System.IO.FileInfo.Delete()    at
>       Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxWorkerManager.CleanupCrashFiles()    at
>       Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxWorkerManager.BackgroundThread(Object
>       job)    at
>       System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>       executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>       preserveSyncCtx)    at
>       System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>       executionContext,  ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>       preserveSyncCtx)    at
>       System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>       executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>       System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)"

Comment: The error seems to be some kind of lock on the temporary files. Have you tried re-starting the sandbox service and/or rebooting the server and see if that helps?